# How to resume MediaPlayer in Android after pressing the home button and reopen the app

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview, onresume

I tried a lot of methods, I made a lot of changes on my code, I read Android MediaPlayer document, I tried StackOverflow examples but none of them could solve my problem.

**My problem:** When I press the home button of emulator or phone then reopen the app it is starting from the beginning.

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

**Here is my code :**

```
public class Mediaplayer extends Activity implements OnCompletionListener,
    OnErrorListener, OnInfoListener, OnPreparedListener,
    OnSeekCompleteListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener,
    SurfaceHolder.Callback, MediaController.MediaPlayerControl {
Display currentDisplay;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
MediaController controller;
int videoWidth = 0;
int videoHeight = 0;
boolean readyToPlay = false;
public final static String LOGTAG = "CUSTOM_VIDEO_PLAYER";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video);

    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) this.findViewById(R.id.SurfaceView);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnInfoListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnSeekCompleteListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(),
            PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
    String filePath = "http://cdn.example.com/wp-content/uploads/Almost.Human-S01E10.mp4";

    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
        finish();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
        finish();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
        finish();
    }

    controller = new MediaController(this);
    currentDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // Log.v(LOGTAG, "surfaceCreated Called");

    mediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);

    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // Log.v(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
        finish();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log.v(LOGTAG, e.getMessage());
        finish();
    }
}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "surfaceChanged Called");
}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "surfaceDestroyed Called");
}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "onCompletion Called");
    finish();
}

public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int whatError, int extra) {
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "onError Called");

    if (whatError == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, "Media Error, Server Died " + extra);
    } else if (whatError == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, "Media Error, Error Unknown " + extra);
    }

    return false;
}

public boolean onInfo(MediaPlayer mp, int whatInfo, int extra) {
    if (whatInfo == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_BAD_INTERLEAVING) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, "Media Info, Media Info Bad Interleaving " + extra);
    } else if (whatInfo == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_NOT_SEEKABLE) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, "Media Info, Media Info Not Seekable " + extra);
    } else if (whatInfo == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_UNKNOWN) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, "Media Info, Media Info Unknown " + extra);
    } else if (whatInfo == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_VIDEO_TRACK_LAGGING) {
        Log.v(LOGTAG, "MediaInfo, Media Info Video Track Lagging " + extra);
        /*
         * Android Version 2.0 and Higher } else if (whatInfo ==
         * MediaPlayer.MEDIA_INFO_METADATA_UPDATE) {
         * Log.v(LOGTAG,"MediaInfo, Media Info Metadata Update " + extra);
         */
    }
    return false;
}

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "onPrepared Called");
    videoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
    videoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();

    if (videoWidth > currentDisplay.getWidth()
            || videoHeight > currentDisplay.getHeight()) {
        float heightRatio = (float) videoHeight
                / (float) currentDisplay.getHeight();
        float widthRatio = (float) videoWidth
                / (float) currentDisplay.getWidth();

        if (heightRatio > 1 || widthRatio > 1) {
            if (heightRatio > widthRatio) {
                videoHeight = (int) Math.ceil((float) videoHeight
                        / (float) heightRatio);
                videoWidth = (int) Math.ceil((float) videoWidth
                        / (float) heightRatio);
            } else {
                videoHeight = (int) Math.ceil((float) videoHeight
                        / (float) widthRatio);
                videoWidth = (int) Math.ceil((float) videoWidth
                        / (float) widthRatio);
            }
        }
    }

    surfaceView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(videoWidth,
            videoHeight));
    mp.start();

    controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
    controller.setAnchorView(this.findViewById(R.id.MainView));
    controller.setEnabled(true);
    controller.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "onSeekComplete Called");
}

public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
    Log.v(LOGTAG, "onVideoSizeChanged Called");
}

public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}

public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return true;
}

public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return true;
}

public int getBufferPercentage() {
    return 0;
}

public int getCurrentPosition() {
    return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
}

public int getDuration() {
    return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
}

public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
}

public void pause() {

    mediaPlayer.pause();

}

public void seekTo(int pos) {
    mediaPlayer.seekTo(pos);
}

public void start() {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

    controller.show();

    return false;
}

@Override
public int getAudioSessionId() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

 }
```

Comment: Just to clarify - you definitely mean the HOME button and not the BACK button?

Comment: Yes i mean HOME button not back button, in other words; when i minimize the app.

Comment: OK - are you restarting the app from the 'recent' list or from the normal app launcher screen?

Comment: Thank you for your care, i'm restarting the app from the 'recent' list.

Comment: I'm not sure what to advise. The only place in your code where `mp.start()` is called is in your `onPrepared(...)` callback method. That method will only be called as a result of using `mp.prepare()` and that is only called in your `surfaceCreated()` method. In theory though if the `MediaPlayer` is simply paused then it should restart when `mpstart()` is called again. Try putting some `Log` calls into `onCreate(...)` to see if the `Activity` is starting over (i.e., it is being recreated).

Comment: When i press the home button, logs were `OnSeekComplete Called` and  `surfaceDestroyed Called` then i press the 'recent' list and press my app, this time logs were  `surfaceCreated Ca.`, `prepareAsync Cal. in state 32`, `surfaceChanged Cal.`, `surfaceDestroyed Cal.` and app is not opening in first press. So i open 'recent' list again and press my app again, this time logs were `surfaceCreated Cal.`, `surfaceChanged Cal.`, `onVideoSizeChanged Cal.`, `onPrepared Called`, `Mpstart Called` (I put the log: 'Mpstart Called').

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I understand you have accepted an answer but I'll explain what the problem was based on your comments on your question and the comments from you and Nana on Nana's answer.

1. A `SurfaceView` is destroyed when it is no longer visible and recreated when it becomes visible again.
2. You are calling `mp.pause()` in your `Activity` `onPause()` method.
3. When you go to the 'recent' apps list and attempt to restart the app, the `SurfaceView` is recreated.
4. In `surfaceCreated` method you are calling `mp.prepare()` but at this point `mp` is in a paused state and calling `prepare()` on a paused `Mediaplayer` will throw an `IllegalStateException`.
5. You have a `try / catch` block which catches `IllegalStateException` and calls `finish()` - this is why the first attempt to restart the app from the 'recent' list causes the the `Activity` to be destroyed.
6. As a result of the above sequence of events you need a second attempt to re-open the app from the 'recent' list but as the `Activity` has been destroyed it will go through a full creation (with `onCreate(..)` being called. This is why it starts from the beginning.

The answer from Nana is a workaround but it will still mean having to use two attempts to restart your `Activity` from the 'recent' list.

Unfortunately the `MediaPlayer` class is lacking in methods for checking the 'state' with `isPlaying` being the only useful method for any state. It's a shame the class devs didn't think to add a `getState()` method (or similar) to allow checking for whether it's started, playing, stopped, paused etc.

One way of preventing the `IllegalStateException` would be to have a boolean called `isPaused` (for example) then modify your `Activity` `onPause()` as follows...

```
if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
    mediaPlayer.pause();
    isPaused = true;
}
```

...and in `surfaceCreated(...)`...

```
try {
    if (isPaused) {
        mpStart();
        isPaused = false;
    }
    else
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
}
// catch blocks here
```

Comment: thank you very much Squonk, i understood my problem now , you are completly right it works great, first attempt is successful now thank you again.

Comment: @user3583237 : Glad I was able to help explain your problem.

Comment: That's an answer. @Squonk, congrats for the simple and kind explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The activity is being restarted thereby triggering surfaceCreated() and mediaPlayer.prepare(), which in turns calls onPrepared and mp.start() to restart the track. You have no mechanism to resume playing. Do this - Get the last position of the track when paused(HOME button is pressed), then when the activity is "recreated" resume playing the track by seeking to that last position. Modify your onPause() and onPrepared() as follows:

```
int length = 0;


//save last position when activity is paused

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
   length = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

    } else {
        return;
    }
}


public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
........
.........
.........
 mp.start();
//seek to saved position. 
 mp.seekTo(length);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i tried this before, but it did not work for me, when i press the 'recent' list app is not opening, it is opening always in my second attempt, and video is starting from the begining. Hope i could explain myself. if you can help me i will be very pleased.

Comment: What's the value of "length" when you pause and return to the app? Try logging "length" in onPause() and onPrepared()

Comment: When i presss the home button. "length" was '8217' it was true then i press recent list and app "length" was still '8217' but app is not opened, I have also problem in this section, i opened recent list and press app again this time length was '0'. I wrote the log cat step by step in my comment.(under my question)

Comment: App doesn't open upon first try in "recent" list? Place a log in the activity's onResume() to check  what happens when the app doesn't open: Log.v(LOGTAG, "onResume Called"); Also, place a log in onDestroy() to check if the app is destroyed. Thanks

Comment: To tell the truth i did not understand anything from my logcat, i did not get any error, anyway when i press the recent list my logs are : `onResume Called`, `surfaceCreated Called`, `prepareAsync called in state 32`, `surfaceChanged Called` , `surfaceDestroyed Called` , length output '8967' , `onDestroy Called`

Comment: i debugged and saw what happens, app is closing in my first attempt(go to black screen and then go to home screen of emulator in milliseconds) after the `mediaplayer.prepare()` in `SurfaceCreated()` method. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Exactly! I've stated this in my updated answer. Hope it solves the problem

Comment: Your first codes works fine, it gets time right and seek to the correct time. Still i need your help about the first attempt failure. Any idea about this problem ?

Comment: Ok! I've reverted to the old answer. Whenever the activity is paused, the surfaceview gets destroyed. Call resume() and pause() methods of the surfaceview from onResume() and onPause() methods of the activity.

Comment: Can you give an example, i think i didn't understand what your are suggesting, did you mean `protected void onResume() { super.onResume()...` ?

Comment: I was referring to the surfaceview: surfaceView = (SurfaceView) this.findViewById(R.id.SurfaceView); It gets destroyed when the activity is paused but I don't think that's the problem because per your logcat stacktrace, the activity is also destroyed. Have you tested on a real device?

Comment: No i did not, tried with android emulator and Genymotion, i hope it is about the emulator. My other mediaplayer codes works fine with my emulators but it is not. I think i'm going to use my other mediaplayer code because i couldn't handle this problem. If a solution comes to your mind please share with me, i really want to solve this problem.

Comment: Ok! No problem. I'll :)